# how to Update Value in local tabel when job Finished

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to update some values into a database as soon as all the tasks of Executing Service have finished executing there jobs.

In other words, I want do something like status when the all jobs finished directly change this status .

I think that doing stored procedure like:

```
Update (Table Name )  Set ( Field ) = 1 )
```

But i don't know, how to execute the stored procedure, when the job finished.

Comment: Just for clarity, is this (1) for each single job as it finishes, or (2) for when all of the jobs in some group finish?

Comment: 2 

for when all of the jobs in some group finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are several apparently semi-independent jobs running, I would suggest implementing a status table and creating a trigger for that table.  It depends on how complex you want to be, but let's keep it to a very simple example.  Perhaps a table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.JobGroupStatus
(Job1 INT,
 Job2 INT,
 Job3 INT,
 Job4 INT,
 Job5 INT
 Job6 INT);
```

When the first job starts it could set all columns to 0.  Then as job one finishes it would "UPDATE dbo.JobGroupStatus SET Job1 = 1", then Job2 when it finishes would update Job2, etc.  Create a trigger on that table that discerns when all jobs have finished.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER UPD_JobGroupStatus ON dbo.JobGroupStatus
 FOR UPDATE 
 AS
 IF (SELECT Job1+Job2+Job3+Job4+Job5+Job6 
     FROM dbo.JobGroupStatus) = 6 
   Update dbo.FinishedJobGroup Set AllDone = 1;
  GO
```

Of  course, you would need to have a periodic check that would determine that apparently all 6 jobs will not finish and report failure.

This little snippet of code is just a toy, not a serious production program. But perhaps it offers you an idea or two about how you might approach your problem.